# What is causing the artifacts in my raytracer?

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, glsl, raytracing

**EDIT**: I have now solved the problem; you can see my solution in the answers.

I'm in the process of writing a realtime raytracer using OpenGL (in a GLSL Compute Shader), and I've run into a slight problem with some of my line-triangle intersections (or at least, I believe they are the culprit).  Here's a picture of what's happening:

[image: Spheres in a room with some artifacts]

As you can see some pixels are being coloured black at the intersection of two triangles near the top of the image.  It's probably got something to do with the way I'm handling floats or something, and I've tried searching for a solution online but can't find similar situations.  Perhaps there's an important keyword I'm missing?

Anyways, the important piece of code is this one:

```
#define EPSILON 0.001f
#define FAR_CLIP 10000.0f
float FindRayTriangleIntersection(Ray r, Triangle p)
{
    // Based on Moller-Trumbone paper
    vec3 E1 = p.v1 - p.v0;
    vec3 E2 = p.v2 - p.v0;
    vec3 T = r.origin - p.v0;
    vec3 D = r.dir;
    vec3 P = cross(D, E2);
    vec3 Q = cross(T, E1);

    float f = 1.0f / dot(P, E1);
    float t = f * dot(Q, E2);
    float u = f * dot(P, T);
    float v = f * dot(Q, D);

    if (u > -EPSILON && v > -EPSILON && u+v < 1.0f+EPSILON) return t;
    else return FAR_CLIP;
}
```

I've tried various values for `EPSILON`, tried variations with +/- for the `EPSILON` values, but to no avail.  Also, changing the `1.0f+EPSILON` to a `1.0-EPSILON` yields a steady black line the whole way across.

Also to clarify, there definitely is NOT a gap between the two triangles.  They are tightly packed (and I have also tried extending them so they intersect, but I still get the same black dots).

Curiously enough, the bottom intersection shows no sign of this phenomenon.

Last note: if more of my code is needed just ask and I'll try to isolate some more code (or maybe just link to the entire shader).

**UPDATE**: It was pointed out that the 'black artifacts' are in fact brown.  So I've dug a bit deeper and turned off all reflections, and got this result:

[image: Spheres without reflections]

The brown colour is actually coming from just the copper material on the top, but more importantly I think I have an idea what the cause of the problem is, but I'm no closer to solving it.

It seems that when the rays get fired out, due to very slight imperfections in the floating arithmetic, some rays intersect the top triangle, and some intersect the bottom.

So I suppose now the question reduces to this: how can I have some sort of consistency in deciding which triangle should be hit in cases like this?

Comment: The pixels aren't black, they're dark brown. The problem is unlikely your ray-triangle intersection code.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful toward a solution, I hadn't realized.  I've updated my post with some further information.

Comment: Try to change your EPSILON to 0.0f - what will happen?

Comment: I get a ton of noise everywhere in the scene, as reflecting rays start self-intersecting the objects they are leaving (meaning pointlight visibility gets fudged, as well as any reflections).

Comment: But you just turned off the reflections, didnt you?

Comment: I did, but when a ray intersects an object, it still needs to generate a new ray to determine if any lights make the point visible.  This new ray is essentially a reflection, and without the `EPSILON` it sometimes just self-intersects the object.  I can update with another picture if you like.

Comment: My point is the 1 px thick line where you see artifacts is the area where the ray intersect both triangles due to your epsilon value. Then, you somehow choose random triangle to display.

Comment: To confirm, you can as well increase epsilon to e.g. 0.005 or decrease to 0.00002, if this will alter the thickness of your error line, you'll know what to check next.

Comment: Your second-last comment actually led me to the solution, so I've updated my post yet again.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Yep, developing numerically stable code is hard. BTW, I do not think you have solved this problem: just change your scene moving your second object by EPSILON closer to your camera, and you should encounter the same problem again.

Comment: You're right, it did just as you suspect.  However I was able to get away with setting the `EPSILON` to 0.0001f, which I think is reasonable.  If I ever have a scene where two triangles are in fact that close together, then there will be artifacts, but I think I can deal with that.  If you can think of a good way to handle this situation that would be great, though I'm fairly happy at this point.

Comment: You could detect such situations (when for a given pixels, there’s a second-nearest triangle that’s within epsilon from the nearest one), and blend the colors of those triangles together.

Comment: If one distance is T1, another T2 so that T1 < T2 and T2-T1<E, you could blend the colors of the triangles using coefficients K2 = 0.5*(T2-T1)/E, K1 = 1.0 - K2 (or even using higher-order function for better results). Main advantage (except fixing the Z-fighting) you will anti-alias some of your edges. Main disadvantage — you will visually “smooth” your geometry, i.e. you will unable to render a polyhedron with sharp edges; however, you can manage both effects by choosing the value of E.

Comment: I've implemented what you described, and it does a pretty good job.  Especially with some anti-aliasing, it's nearly undetectable.  Thanks again!

Comment: You’re welcome. And one more minor improvement. I would try to choose E based on the T1, i.e. E = someSmallValue*T1. Due to the nature of the floating-points, absolute error is proportional to the value. That’s why with variable E value you’ll probably get slightly more consistent result between the edges that are close to the camera, and edges that are far away near the FAR_CLIP plane.

Comment: Also, plz post ur pix :-)

Comment: Could you please add your solution as an answer? This is easier for people browsing the site. :) Your question also showed up in my weekly newsletter in the 'Can you answer these?' section, while it shouldn't have.

Comment: I'm planning to post my solution with pictures later today after work.  Sorry about that!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So it turns out it was not the code I had posted that caused the problem.  Thanks to some help in the comment, I was able to find it was this code when I'm determining the nearest object to the camera:

```
float nearest_t = FAR_CLIP;
int nearest_index = 0;
for (int j=0; j<NumObjects; j++)
{
    float t = FAR_CLIP;
    t = FindRayObjectIntersection(r, objects[j]);

    if (t < nearest_t && t > EPSILON && t < FAR_CLIP)
    {
        nearest_t = t;
        nearest_index = j;
    }
}
```

When determining t, sometimes the triangles were so close together that the `t < nearest_t` had an almost probabilistic result, since the intersections were roughly the same distance from the camera.

My initial solution was to change the inner if-statement to:

```
if (t < nearest_t-EPSILON && t > EPSILON && t < FAR_CLIP)
```

This ensures that if two intersections are very close together, it will always choose the first object to display (unless the second object is closer by at least `EPSILON`).  Here is a resulting image (with reflections disabled):

[image: Spheres]

Now there were still some small artifacts, so it was clear that there was still a slight problem.  So upon some discussion in the comments, @Soonts came up with the idea of blending the triangles' colours.  This lead me to have to change the above code further in order to keep track of the distance to both triangles:

```
if (t > EPSILON && t < FAR_CLIP && abs(nearest_t - t) < EPSILON)
{
    nearest_index2 = nearest_index;
    nearest_t2 = nearest_t;
}
if (t < nearest_t+EPSILON && t > EPSILON && t < FAR_CLIP)
{
    nearest_t = t;
    nearest_index = j;
}
```

I also added this colour blending code:

```
OverallColor = mix(c1, c2, 0.5f * abs(T1 - T2) / EPSILON);
```

After these two steps, and honestly I think this effect was more from the logic change than the blending change, I got this result:

[image: Spheres]

I hope others find this solution helpful, or at the very least that it sparks some ideas to solve your own problems.  As a final example, here is the beautiful result with reflections, softer shadows and some anti-aliasing all turned on:

[image: Happy raytracing]

Happy raytracing!